# Remove wallpaper that has been textured over

Tags: bathroom, plaster, repainting, wallpaper

Our bathroom has textured plaster work that seems to have been put on over the top of wallpaper. You can see some of the seams and the wallpaper was also still there under a mirrored cabinet. Above the door, for example, the wallpaper is peeling. We would like to get rid of the texture on the walls.

Would it be possible  to just   take down the wallpaper that the plaster is on top of and hope that the walls underneath are acceptable for repainting?

Or

Can we sand down the textured plaster work?

(*We would like to be able to paint and  have it be a smoother surface*).

Comment: "Would it be possible?" try it and find out. Worst case, you'll damage the wall and need to repair it, but you're basically looking at doing that anyway.

Comment: I doubt it is plaster.   Do you have a picture?

Answer (score 2):

Removing wall paper   can be a major pain in the posterior  at best. With plaster on top it may be a nightmare, if doable. You could try it in a small test area.

It *may be?* easier and or less time consuming to skim coat a new layer of mud and sand smooth, but that requires skill that a DIY'er may not have (*but with practice could do*).

Maybe remove the dry wall and install new drywall, Again mudding and taping is an acquired skill, especially when you want a smooth non textured wall, it take a lot of prep to get smooth.